# Yii query builder

Tags: sql, yii

How build this query with YIi query builder

```
SELECT First_Name,User_ID,
FROM `Users`
WHERE First_name LIKE $_GET['name']
```

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Örs said everything is in the [Yii Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder)!

```
$user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('First_Name, User_ID')
    ->from('Users')
    ->where('First_name like :name', array(':name'=>$_GET['name']))
    ->queryRow();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$cr = new CDbCriteria();
$cr->condition = "First_name LIKE '%:name%'";
$cr->params = array(':name'=>$_GET['name']);

$users = Users::model()->findAll($cr);
```

Another way

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some explanation to your code, showing what it does and how it solves the problem posed in the question. This will help others who see your answer in the future